# ImageView out of layout bounds

Tags: android, layout, imageview

i have an imageview on a relative layout.
You can see in the screenshot :[image]
 How can i move the imageview(the weel) in the bottom-right corner, but display only 25 % part of it, like in the follow picture:
[image]

Thanks in advance !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#E0E0E0"
  >
<com.androidsources.welcomescreen.MyRecyclerView
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/cardList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
  <com.anupcowkur.wheelmenu.WheelMenu
    android:id="@+id/wheelMenu"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"


    android:src="@drawable/wheel"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your xml layout

Comment: please check the edited post

Comment: I want to be anchored dinamically to any screen size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<com.anupcowkur.wheelmenu.WheelMenu
    android:id="@+id/wheelMenu"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingLeft="150dp"
    android:paddingTop="150dp"

    android:src="@drawable/wheel"/>
```

`alignParentRight` and `alignParentBottom` attributes will move your widget at the right bottom corner. Also try to change `padding` to achieve desired visual effect.

Comment: tried that but it didn't work for me, I wonder why? Mine works if I enclose the image inside linearlayout.

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is already an answer, but for those who can't make the accepted answer work here is an alternative.

For some reason, I can't place part of the view outside the parent if I'm using `RelativeLayout` but when I tried `LinearLayout` it worked. So the solution I used is to enclose the view in a `LinearLayout` then position the `LinearLayout` on bottom-end of the parent.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/some_pic"
        android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note the width and height of the image is not `match_parent`, using `match_parent` will shrink the image not displace it.